# Converting integers into time format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
data = {"hours": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have been trying to get the following format of time:

```
1:00:00, 2:00:00 ... 12:00:00 etc
```

so that at the end when typing `df.dtypes` I get the follwoing format as well: `datetime64[ns]`
but unfortunately I was not successful. I have tried the following:

```
df['new_hours'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hours'])
```

but it did not work.

Comment: `pd.to_timedelta(df['hours'], unit='h')`?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"hours": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['hours'] = (pd.Timestamp('now').normalize() + (pd.to_timedelta(df['hours'], unit='h'))).dt.time

print(df.head())
#       hours
# 0  01:00:00
# 1  02:00:00
# 2  03:00:00
# 3  04:00:00
# 4  05:00:00
```

Explanation:

- `df['hours'] =`  overwrites the Series named 'hours'
- `(pd.Timestamp('now').normalize()` creates a datetime'now' and normalize() makes it a midnight datetime (e.g. today 00:00:00)
- `+ (pd.to_timedelta(df['hours'],unit='h'))` creates a Timedelta object based on the integer in the 'hours' Series, unit parameter ensures its interpreted as hour. Adds this to the previous midnight datetime.
- `).dt.time` takes the time of the datetime that was constructed in the previous 2 bull-its.